# Testcafe: How to update the store of userRole

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testcafe, user-roles, refresh-token

Using `userRole`, I try to avoid having to log in before each test, but my test suite is running long, so the app goes fetching a new accessToken based on the current refershToken a number of times. This causes tests to fail sometimes, and after some investigation, I discovered that the `localStorage` seems only to be stored at login time, not at test exit time. So when a refresh happened, the next test does get the wrong accessToken and an expired refreshToken, so the app fails. (Which probably should not happen and simply present a login screen, but that is beside the point, as that is a scenario that should not happen in these tests.)
How can I make sure that the Role is updated with the latest version of `localStorage` upon exiting the test?

This is the test code to isolate the problem:

```
test('xxx', async t => {
  await t.useRole(anAdminUser)
  await ClientFunction(() => window.localStorage.setItem('xxx', 'xxx'))()
  await t.expect(await ClientFunction(() => window.localStorage.getItem('xxx'))()).eql('xxx')
}
test('yyy', async t => {
  await t.useRole(anAdminUser)
  await t.expect(await ClientFunction(() => window.localStorage.getItem('xxx'))()).eql('xxx') /* => fail */
}
```

I finally worked around the problem using:

```
fixture('aaa')
  .beforeEach(async t => {
    await t.useRole(anAdminUser)
    const { sessionCache } = anAdminUser
    if (!anAdminUser.sessionCache) return
    await ClientFunction(sessionCache => window.localStorage.setItem('xxx', sessionCache))(sessionCache)
  })
  .afterEach(async () => {
    const sessionCache = await ClientFunction(() => window.localStorage.getItem('xxx'))()
    anAdminUser.sessionCache = sessionCache
  })
```

but it seems like a waste to duplicate some of the efforts of `useRole` itself.

Comment: I also created a ticket on testcafé's GitHub to solve it in the framework itself: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4492